# /tmp/.X11-unix: mount point does not exist

Tags: x11, windows-subsystem-for-linux, rdp

I installed [Athena OS](https://apps.microsoft.com/store/detail/athena-os/9N1M7Q4F1KQF) on WSL. I installed Win-KeX via pacman. Attempting to start Win-KeX is problematic. The mountpoint `/tmp/.X11-unix`does not exist.

`kex --win -s`

```
Starting Win-KeX server (Win)
 mount: /tmp/.X11-unix: mount point does not exist.
   dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.

    /tmp/.X11-unix is still read-only
    Win-KeX server (Win) is stopped

Error connecting to the Win-KeX server (Win)
Please try "/usr/sbin/kex start" to start the service
If the server fails to start, please try "/usr/sbin/kex kill" or restart your WSL 2 session and try again

Starting Win-KeX client (Win)
```

`sudo mount -o remount,rw /tmp/.X11-unix`

```
mount: /tmp/.X11-unix: mount point does not exist.
   dmesg(1) may have more information after failed mount system call.
```

`sudo umount /tmp/.X11-unix`

```
umount: /tmp/.X11-unix: no mount point specified.
```

`ls -l /tmp/.X11-unix/`

```
lsd: /tmp/.X11-unix/: No such file or directory (os error 2).
```

Answer (score 0):

The command

```
ln -s /mnt/wslg/.X11-unix /tmp/.X11-unix
```

resolved the problem.